# MySql query to check for duplicate ips

Tags: mysql

I need to know if there's any method to do the task below using only a mysql query.
I want to check if 2 accounts have on the last_login_from columm the same IP adress. I want the query to return all the rows that don't have an unique value on the last_login_from columm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * 
from accounts a
where a.last_login_from IN 
    ( select last_login_from 
      from accounts
      group by last_login_from
      having count(*)>1 )
```

Comment: this has an O(N*N) complexity ?

Comment: @Cristy, not if you index the column, and do you have enough accounts for it to matter?

Comment: I was just asking...Thanks :D